# Replace new line character by comma in SED

Tags: sed, replace

I have the following csv data in a file.

```
14,95884250,ENSG00000176438,C,T,A
CCAATCAGA
14,95884250,ENSG00000176438,C,T,A
CAATCAGAG
```

I would like to replace alternate new line character by ',' (preferably using 'sed'). The desired output is below.

```
14,95884250,ENSG00000176438,C,T,A,CCAATCAGA
14,95884250,ENSG00000176438,C,T,A,CAATCAGAG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give this awk one-liner a try:

```
awk 'NR%2{printf "%s,",$0;next}{print}' file
```

Comment: Working fine!! How can I add a comma before 'CCAATCAGA' 'CAATCAGAG' string.

Comment: @rshar the comma should be there already, there is a `,` after `%s`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/\n/,/' file
```

Append the next line and replace the newline by a comma.

Comment: This will not work. With the `N` command the current line number changes.

Comment: @leo what line number?

Comment: The one currently being read.